# update an array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

I have an object inside I have an array called: "timeFrame" which contains more objects. I'm trying to update my MongoDB so that the `timeFrame` array will be updated according to the new object which means that the same values in a specific index of the new object will be in the old array.

My object:

```
var newMsg = {  
        "screensId":[parseInt(screenId)],
        "name":"msg6",
        "text":["Won the lottery?","Want to invest your money?","Shulberg investment company","Your money is important to us!"],
        "images":["http://thefilipinoexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/04_investment.jpg"],
        "template":"/html/templateA.html",
        "msgTime":5000,
        "timeFrame":[
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], "startTime" : 6, "endTime" : 23},
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [5], "startTime" : 13, "endTime" : 20}]  }
```

My update code:

```
updateMessage = function(msg) {
    db.collection('messages').update({"name": msg.name},{$set:{msgTime: msg.msgTime,template: msg.template,screensId: msg.screensId,text: msg.text,images: msg.images,timeFrame:msg.timeFrame}},{upsert: false}); 
};
```

I also tried `timeFrame.$` but it doesn't work well because I want that every index in the timeFrame array of the new object will be copied to the old one.

I'm using MongoDB version 2.6 standard if it helps.

An example for change in timeFrame:

```
 "timeFrame":[
            { "startDate" : [2017,1,1], "endDate" : [2018,11,21], "days" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], "startTime" : 5, "endTime" : 23},
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [5], "startTime" : 13, "endTime" : 20}]  }
```

the new one:

```
"timeFrame":[
            { "startDate" : [2016,0,1], "endDate" : [2016,11,31], "days" : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], "startTime" : 6, "endTime" : 23},
            { "startDate" : [2019,4,25], "endDate" : [2019,11,28], "days" : [5], "startTime" : 8, "endTime" : 20}]  }
```

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand your question. Can you give me examples of the object before and after the update please?

Comment: i just edited my message with an example for changing timeFrame what i want is to copy the new one on the old one using update of mongoDB

Comment: I still do not understand "which means that the same values in a specific index of the new object will be in the old array". When I look at your examples, you are just pushing another timeFrame and remove the oldest one. But where is that wanted behaviour? And where is the new timeFrame created?

Comment: well but this is exactly what i want to do i mean that im getting from the browser a json to edit i then search for it in the db and then i want to set the new timeFrame (which is just the editing of the client) and replace the old one but how can i do so?? the json object is just the msg the function got and the json object above is just an example so you will know how it look like

Comment: Okay, let me recap. You are receiving an updated message from the user (var newMsg). You are searching this message in the database, you are updating all the values on the first level, you are removing the first record from your array and you are adding the timeFrame (from var newMsg) to the timeFrame array. Is that correct?

Comment: well its almost correct what im trying to do is not adding the timeFrame (from var newMsg) but to replace the old timeFrame with the new one from var newMsg

Comment: Have you tried `db.collection('messages').update({"name": msg.name}, msg); `?

Comment: yea but it didnt work but when i did: db.collection('messages').update({"name": msg.name},{$set:{"timeFrame.0.startDate":msg.timeFrame[0].startDate}}); it did replace the startDate with the new one but how can i change the .0 to something like parameter so i can loop on everything and change it as well??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100284/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-elad-doocker).